# Why has create pins stopped working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I just finished One Month Rails, and somewhere during the last two videos, I stopped being able to create new pins when logged in.

The issue occurs when a user is logged in and tries to add a new pin.

Here is the error I get:

```
NoMethodError in PinsController#create
undefined method `name' for #<Pin:0x41e0c08>
Extracted source (around line #22):   
def create
@pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
if @pin.save
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
else
  render action: 'new'
```

pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
@pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>    20)
end

def show
end

def new
@pin = current_user.pins.build
end

def edit
end

def create
@pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
if @pin.save
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
else
  render action: 'new'
end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy

validates :name, presence: true
validates :name, length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

**Edit** So I followed Doon's advice and checked the models, and changed them to:

user.rb

```
has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy

validates :name, presence: true
validates :name, length: { minimum: 2 }
```

pin.rb

```
validates :image, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
```

This seemed to eliminate the first error message, but now I see a new one:

```
NameError in Pins#show
undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x3e41920>:0x4e1bbe8>
```

from show.html.erb

```
<% if current_user && pin.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to edit_pin_path(@pin) do %>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
Edit
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Help (again)?

Comment: Did you drop a column called `name`?

Comment: You can't link to an entire Github repo for debugging help here, or to a live site. Your question needs to contain a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Now that you've edited, this is a different question. Which is fine, but deprives the people who've given time and effort to existing answers the chance to have resolved the problem. If they fixed your first question, mark the answers right and open a new question. (Your new problem is that you're looking for `pin.user` when you should be after `@pin.user`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at your db/schema.rb  you will see there is no name field there.

but if you look at app/models/pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }


     validates :image, presence: true
     validates :description, presence: true
     validates :name, length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

you will see a validates :name,  which you probably mistakenly added to that file as opposed to user.rb.   you cannot validate a non existent field.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are accessing field `name` somewhere in `Pin` model BUT the field `name` doesn't exist in either your `pins` table or as a *virtual attribute* in model `Pin`. This is resulting in the error `undefined method 'name' for #<Pin:0x41e0c08>`